# Outputting a decimal value in Cpp

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ using a book and currently, I'm reading the section about formating output data using manipulators. There is a program written to output data once without showing the base and again with its base. It is a simple program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int x = 1237;
        
        cout<<"x in decimal: "<< x << endl;
        cout<<"x in octal: "<<oct<< x << endl;
        cout<<"x in hexadecimal: "<< hex << x << endl << endl;
        
        cout<<"x in decimal: " << x << endl;
        cout<<"x in octal: " << showbase << oct << x << endl;
        cout<<"x in hexadecimal: " << showbase << hex << x << endl;
        
        return 0;
        }
```

When the program is run the output is:

```
    x in decimal: 1237 
    x in octal: 2325 
    x in hexadecimal: 4d5
        
    x in decimal: 4d5 
    x in octal: 02325 
    x in hexadecimal: 0x4d5
```

That is, in the line containing `x in decimal` the value is in `hex` rather than `dec`. I've compiled and run this code both using GCC and cpp.sh website but the result is not what is now in the book indicating a decimal value.
Could anyone please explain to me why does this happen and how could I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please inform yourself, [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question is _off-topic_ because this site is for reviewing code you write. [“_For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers. We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is._”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Yeah, Surely you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably better fit to StackOverflow. The reason is that the `std::hex`manipulator is persistent. You must explicitly switch back to decimal.

Comment: Yes, I added `dec` at that line and it worked! Would you please tell me, why Code Review isn't suitable for this question? Thank you

Comment: I'm by far not a StackExchange veteran, but my understanding is that StackOverflow is for code that does not work as expected and questions about specific things, whereas CodeReview is for code that works and is finished, but the author wants to know what could have been done better.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for being so informative!

Comment: [Please refrain from answering questions that are likely to get closed.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/35991). in the future please use the  [flag option](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) until you gain the [cast close and reopen votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I saw the question is not ok, but given the simplicity I decided to answer anyway. I did not know that an accepted answer forbids mods from deleting the question (which is what I assumed would happen). Sorry about that.